# Append the returned html from function using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react,

I am trying to append the html from the return function within the same component,

here is my code

```
// reactstrap components
import {useState} from "react"
import {
  Badge,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardFooter,
  Button,
  UncontrolledTooltip,
} from "reactstrap";
// core components
//import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "components/Headers/Header.js";
  import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import Navbar from "components/Navbars/modulenavbar"

// const dropdownedit=(editid)=>{
  
//   alert("clicked");
//   console.log(editid.target.value);
 
//   return dropdownedit;
// }npm install react-bootstrap-icons
import axios from "axios";
//import data from "./data";
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
var apitoken= localStorage.getItem('apitoken');
//const api=axios.create({baseURL:"https://api/v1/user/login",headers: {'Authorization ': apitoken}})
const api=axios.create({baseURL:"https://api/account"})
const options = {
  headers: {'Authorization': apitoken}
}


var accountarry=[];

const Accounts = () => {

 
  const [accounts, setaccount] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [selectedStudent, setSelectedStudent] = useState({});
  
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await api.get("/",options);
    accountarry=response.data.response
    setaccount(accountarry);
    setLoading(false);
  }, []); 
  const handleScroll = e => {
    let element = e.target
    if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight) {
      // do something at end of scroll
      console.log("End")
      accountarry.push({"name":"arrayvalue"})

    }}
    const Save = (event) => {
    alert("ok");
    return<>
    
    <Row>
                <div className="col">
               
                  <FormGroup>
                  
                    <Input
                      className="form-control-alternative"
                      placeholder="Comments"
                      rows="4"
                      id="input-notes"
                       defaultValue="dynamic append"
                      type="textarea"
                      disabled={disabled}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                  
                </div>
                <Col className="col-auto">
                <UncontrolledDropdown>
                        <DropdownToggle
                          className="btn-icon-only text-light"
                          href="#pablo"
                          role="button"
                          size="sm"
                          color=""
                          onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                        >
                          <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-v" />
                        </DropdownToggle>
                        <DropdownMenu className="dropdown-menu-arrow" right>
                          {/* <DropdownItem value="9566412482" id="dropdown-menu-align-right" onClick={handleGameClick}>  */}
                          {/* <DropdownItem value={id} id="dropdown-menu-align-right" to={`/admin/editcontact?id=${id}`} tag={Link}> */}
                          
                            
                          {/* </DropdownItem> */}
                          <DropdownItem
                            href="#pablo"
                            onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                          >
                            Delete
                          </DropdownItem>                  
                        </DropdownMenu>
                      </UncontrolledDropdown>
                </Col>
                
              </Row>
    
    </>
    }
   const Handlestudentclick = (student) => {
    setSelectedStudent(student)
  }

  if (loading) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }
  
  return (
    <>
     <Header />
  {/* Page content */}
  <Container className="mt--0"  fluid>
    
    <Row>
  
      <Col className="order-xl-1" xl="12">
    <Card className="bg-secondary shadow">
   
          
              <Row>

              
    <Col xs="9">
   
   

    <Card className="card-stats mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <CardBody>

              
             <div>
             <Save/>
             <Row>
                <div className="col">
               
                  <FormGroup>
                  
                    <Input
                      className="form-control-alternative"
                      placeholder="Comments"
                      rows="4"
                      id="input-notes"
                      // defaultValue="A beautiful Dashboard for Bootstrap 4. It is Free and
                      // Open Source."
                      type="textarea"
                      // disabled={disabled}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                  
                </div>

              </Row>

              <Row className="align-items-center">
                <Col xs="8">
                 
                </Col>
                <Col className="text-right" xs="4">
                  <Button
                    color="success"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={save}
                    
                  >
                    Save
                  </Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            
             </div>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>


    </Col>
               
     
     </Row>
    
     </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
   
  </Container>
      
    </>
  )
}


const Display = () => {
 return (
  <>

 
      
           
     <Accounts/>
     
</>
  );
};

export default Display;
```

In the above code i have used **button onclick={save}** so the save function will run and return the html for append it in the same component below save, .

I dont know how to do this in react , can you help me of what i have done wrong here.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your `save` function returns html has no effect right now, because you don't do anything with it. The clicked button executes a function and gets some html in return, it's useless :).

The actual, working flow could be:

1. Create a state variable that holds the additional html to render (or `null` if there's no additional html).
2. Modify your `save` function to, instead of returning the code, set this state variable accordingly.
3. Place this state variable within your returned html, so that setting it will result in actualy rendering the additional html.

The basic example is:

```
const [additional, setAdditional] = useState(null);

const save = () => {
    const myAdditionalHtml = (
        <div>additional</div>
    );

    setAdditional(myAdditionalHtml);
}

return (
    <>
        <div>my standard code
        {additional}
        <button onClick={() => save()}>save</button>
    </>
);
```